# Vonk FHIR server Bundle validation issue

Tags: hl7-fhir

When posting the [FHIR example that uses the ZIB for tobacco use](https://simplifier.net/nictizstu3-zib2017/observation-example-duplicate-6) to the Vonk FHIR server in a transaction, Vonk responds with an error.

Request body:

```
{
    "type": "transaction",
    "entry": [
        {
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Observation",
                "id": "medmij-bgz-tobaccouse-ts-01",
                "meta": {
                    "profile": [
                        "http://nictiz.nl/fhir/StructureDefinition/zib-TobaccoUse"
                    ]
                },
                "status": "final",
                "code": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                            "code": "365980008",
                            "display": "Finding of tobacco use and exposure (finding)"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "subject": {
                    "reference": "Patient/medmij-bgz-patient-ts-01",
                    "display": "Johan XXX_Helleman"
                },
                "effectivePeriod": {
                    "start": "1980",
                    "end": "1983"
                },
                "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                            "code": "8517006",
                            "display": "Ex-smoker (finding)"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "component": [
                    {
                        "code": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                                    "code": "53661000146106",
                                    "display": "Type of tobacco used (observable entity)"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "valueCodeableConcept": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                                    "code": "65568007",
                                    "display": "Cigarette smoker (finding)"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "code": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                                    "code": "266918002",
                                    "display": "Tobacco smoking consumption (observable entity)"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "valueQuantity": {
                            "value": "2",
                            "unit": "packs per week",
                            "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
                            "code": "{packs}/wk"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "code": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                                    "code": "401201003",
                                    "display": "Cigarette pack-years (observable entity)"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "valueQuantity": {
                            "value": "1",
                            "unit": "PackYears",
                            "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
                            "code": "{PackYears}"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "request": {
                "url": "Observation/medmij-bgz-tobaccouse-ts-01",
                "method": "PUT"
            }
        }
    ],
    "resourceType": "Bundle"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "resourceType": "OperationOutcome",
    "id": "d230a0cd-5487-489b-8f19-098f66e55744",
    "meta": {
        "versionId": "ca7e8081-6557-4eba-9a9f-14df426a0ff2",
        "lastUpdated": "2019-03-11T09:07:56.638+00:00"
    },
    "issue": [
        {
            "severity": "error",
            "code": "invalid",
            "details": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/dotnet-api-operation-outcome",
                        "code": "1008"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Value is not exactly equal to fixed value 'http://unitsofmeasure.org'"
            },
            "location": [
                "Observation.component[2].value[0].system[0]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "severity": "warning",
            "code": "not-supported",
            "details": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/dotnet-api-operation-outcome",
                        "code": "5003"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Argument is not supported"
            },
            "location": [
                "/Observation"
            ]
        },
        {
            "severity": "warning",
            "code": "not-supported",
            "details": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/dotnet-api-operation-outcome",
                        "code": "5003"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Argument is not supported"
            },
            "location": [
                "/medmij-bgz-tobaccouse-ts-01"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems the error complains about an URL mismatch in the `PackYears` component, however, that is exactly using the url `http://unitsofmeasure.org` as indicated should be used in the error. Does anybody know if the request is wrong here or Vonk has an issue?

Notice that posting without a transaction to `/Observation/` does NOT give an error but completes successfully.
Also notice that the `/Bundle/$validate` request for the same bundle does NOT indicate any errors, but responds with `The operation was successful`.

We are using Vonk 1.1.0 and have configured it to use a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in Vonk. I can reproduce it with Vonk version 1.1.0. We will release a new version of Vonk next week, where this has been resolved.